# If I code sign my Application (exe file) once with CA authorized certificate , will it reflect where ever I install it?

Tags: certificate, code-signing, certificate-authority

I am developing a desktop application. I can code sign it with .pfx file. I will get that from CA. But what if I want to install it in a different system. Will it reflect there as well? Because I can't share my .pfx file with everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should not share the `*pfx` as it contains the private key.
2. The **trust** to the signature comes from the **trust chain** - so when the issuing CA and all intermediate CAs up to the root CA are in the **trust store** (`Windows Trust Store`, `MAC Key Chain` or `cacerts.pem` for OpenSSL/Java) the signature is trusted as long as

   - the certificate is not revoked
   - the signature certificate is not expired or the signature contains a counter signature (RFC3161 timestamp).

Comment: Welcome. If the answer is correct, please flag it, so other ppl know this worked out.

Comment: Done. I have one question though. My application is already deployed. Many users have downloaded and using it locally. Code signing my .exe locally would not affect other systems. I have not done any code change, so no point in sharing my recent code with them. So, how will it reflect other systems? Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean with *reflect other systems*? Does *My application is already deployed* with a signature?

Comment: I mean when the user installs my desktop application, it says it is from an unknown publisher. To overcome this, I wanted to code signing. When I do code sign in my local machine, I won't see this alert again. But how can I make this happen for all my users who are using my Application (exe)? @Daniel Fisher lennybacon

Comment: When you sign it with a code signing certificate issued by a publicly CA it is trusted by everyone that trusts this CA. If you open `certlm.msc` you can find a list of *Trusted Root Certificate Authorities*. The certificate that does the signature must chain up to one of these certificates - if that is given no notification is shown. So get a code signing certificate form a well known seller and ensure you do not have old clients (WinXP, Vista, 7) as there are other roots CAs trusted and the SHA1/SHA265 issues beside that the OSs are not supported anymore.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, Daniel